# A few questions regarding Pythons 'import' feature

Tags: python, import

I just downloaded Beautiful Soup and I've decided I'll make a small library (is that what they call them in Python?) that will return results of a movie given and IMDB movie search.

My question is, how exactly does this import thing work?

For example, I downloaded BeautifulSoup and all it is, is a .py file. Does that file have to be in the same folder as the my python application (my project that will use the library)?

Comment: What OS are you using? The standard way to install any module (like BeautifulSoup) depends on the OS.

Comment: Ubuntu, ironically. :) (your username)

Comment: "is that what they call them in Python?" You should probably get a Python tutorial and actually do the tutorial first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917958/python-import-mechanics/1918211#1918211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu, you can search for packages with the command

```
apt-cache search beautifulsoup
```

This should yield

```
python-beautifulsoup - error-tolerant HTML parser for Python
```

So the easiest way to install BeautifulSoup for ubuntu would be to run

```
sudo apt-get install python-beautifulsoup
```

Once you do this, you can put

```
import BeautifulSoup
```

in any of your scripts and your python installation will find the module.

Answer (score 3):

BeautifulSoup.py will need to be placed somewhere on the Python search path, which is available to you in the `sys.path` array. Note that the current directory is always included in this array (as the empty string).

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python26.zip', 'c:\\python26\\DLLs', 'c:\\python26\\lib', 'c:\\python26\\lib\\plat-win', 'c
:\\python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'c:\\python26', 'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages', 'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32'
, 'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: I just placed the .py file into my usr/Sergio/home folder and it's now found. However what would happen if I want to deploy an application that uses this library?

Answer (score 1):

See the [module search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). For your case, placing the .py file in the same folder will work.

Answer (score 1):

Python *modules* are top level entities in python programs that can be imported (analogous to C files). There is a load path which contains a list of directories to search for modules when you're importing them. I'd recommend that you go through [the modules section of the official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) for details (and through the whole tutorial as well).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation on [packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages). When you import a package, python searches within `sys.path`, so you must place Beautiful Soup within the path, or append a new directory to the path.

Example:

```
import sys
print "Before:\n", sys.path
sys.path.append('/some/directory')
print "After:\n", sys.path
```

Comment: How to append new directory to the path? Can you please give an example?

Answer (score -1):

Might not be relevant, but have you considered using imdbpy? Last time I used it it worked pretty well...