# How to call the functions present in one .py file from other .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have two files and I'd like to import a class from the other file.

File `one.py`:

```
class One: 
    def printNumber( self, a ):
        print (a)
```

and file `two.py`:

```
#import One # gives error no module named One
#import one # gives error no module named one

class Two:
  # Here I want to call printNumber method from one.py
```

Comment: Have you tried Googling, "how to import in Python"?

Comment: if this is python 2, which judging by the syntax it is you may need to have a file named '__init__.py' in the same directory (Can't get the underscore syntax.... )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python import mechanics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917958/python-import-mechanics)

Answer (score 0):

**Keep the files in the same directory** then use something like the below format.

```
from one import One

one = One()

class Two:
    a = 5
    one.printNumber(a)
```

Edit: When working in Pycharm you need to mark your sources root to import your own files.

[image]

Comment: Using from also giving the same error. Both files are in same directory. I'm using pycharm IDE

Comment: Updated my answer for use with Pycharm.

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: @Sumith - Please accept this answer if it solved your issue. Thanks!