# when i import module it runs the whole python file

Tags: python, python-import

client.py

```
# Importing modules
import os
import asyncio
import sys
import Events
import glob
import Plugins
global FPath
global PlugPath
global CMDPath
FPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PlugPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "\\Plugins"

Events.Startup()
global cmds
cmds = input("\\>")
global commandlst
commandlst = cmds.split()
command = commandlst[0]
runpy = "python " + str(FPath) + "\\" +  str(command) + ".py"
if(os.path.isfile(FPath + "\\" + command + ".py") == True):
    os.system(runpy)
else:
    print(command + " is not a command or a plugin command!")
    os.system("ping localhost -n 2 >nul")
    os.system("py client.py")
```

help.py

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint
import os
import sys
import client
commands = json.loads(open(sys.path[0] + "\\commands.json").read())
```

when it imports client it runs the entire client.py file.
i have tried from client import commandlst and nothing works.
please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python import mechanics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917958/python-import-mechanics)

Comment: That's how Python works. When you import a module in Python it executes everything in that code. If you don't want some part of code to be executed you should write it inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is how importing works. To solve your particular problem - do not run the whole `client.py` module you can place it's content into `if __name__ == '__main__':` check like this:

```
# Importing modules
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    global FPath
    ...
```